# no tilde expansion in GNU make recipe

Tags: makefile

I face a problem that the CC path contain ~ is not expand, a simple code to demonstrate is:

```
$ cat test.mk

all:
        @echo CC=~/toolchain/"crosstool-ipq4018"/bin/"arm-linux-gnueabihf"-gcc

$ make -f test.mk
CC=~/toolchain/crosstool-ipq4018/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

Comment: @MadScientist hi

Comment: The default shell used by make is `sh`, not `bash`. Type `sh -c 'echo CC=~/foo'` in your terminal and you'll understand. Add `SHELL := bash` to your Makefile if you want `bash`. Or type `make SHELL=bash`.

Comment: Or, use `$(HOME)` or `$$HOME` instead of `~`.

Comment: @MadScientist I tested. `CC=~/xxx make` works ok, but `make CC=~/xxx` only work on bash shell. the dash shell can't do tilde expansion on arguments if it isn't a path, e.g. `sh -c "echo ~/abc"` will do tilde expansion, but `sh -c "echo CC=~/abc"` will not

Comment: Not sure why you addressed that to me: nothing about what you've said is surprising. Renaud provided this answer already so I didn't need to say anything.  If you run `X=~/foo make` then your current shell expands `X` before calling make.  If you run `make X=~/foo` then the value of `X` is expanded by the shell that make invokes.  It all makes perfect sense.  This is why my suggestion is to not use `~` at all, and instead use the `HOME` environment variable.